# 1045 Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'

Tags: php, magento, web, cpanel, access-denied

> 1045 Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'(using password:
>   YES)

I am newbie to all this web hosting stuff but I do looked up a lot of related articles and tried many ways to solve it but problems still here. Really need help.

This is what my website shows now. I have looked up many articles here and all of them mention edit file (`config.inc.php`) via Xampp. But the problem is I am not using my own computer as the server and I am paying for hosting.

So, how can I solve this through my cPanel? I cannot locate the file (`config.inc.php`) in my File Manager of my hosting.

Also,the user get access denied is the admin user as I do not create any new user for the web so I wonder why I will receive access denied for my admin user.

I am quite hopeless at this point. Hope some of you can give me some insight on what's going wrong.
Thanks a lot

This is the document I have in my file manager inside cPanel. Btw, I am using magento.

[image]

[P.S. This is the original error report. Any professions know how it happens. Is it referring to some connection problems? Some files has been removed?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASBmD.jpg)

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Would you be able to create a new user through phpmyadmin?

Comment: what code do you referring to?

Comment: Do you mean by creating new database user for the database of which my website is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what 1045 is but if everyone mentioned that you should change something in the `config.inc.php` then I know what it is.

The file should be in `xampp\phpMyAdmin`. Open it and change the value at `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` from `'config'` to `'cookie'`.

If you're using passwords for your database, then you need to change it for getting access to the database.

Comment: Isn't Xampp is used for people using their own computer as server? As I do have a web hosting company. So,I am using the cPanel instead of Xampp. I cannot find file'config.inc.php' in the file manager of my cPanel

Comment: @AndyMak Sorry, didn't read the question clearly. Just to clarify everthing for me: You have a hoster, which uses a cPanel for controlling and your database is set up on their hoster, correct? So there's no xampp or phpMyAdmin in this setup? Maybe this article can help you: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/databases/1045-access-denied-for-user-mysql-error

Comment: @AndyMak xampp doesn't need to be locally on your computer. You can use it on a server. You only need to change the configuration. As far as I know.

Comment: Thanks a lot first. This is exactly my case. I have a setup web with with paid hosting,not the case using Xampp for testing web using own computer as server. I have looked up the article you said. But, the case is I have only one database and one user which is the admin user. As I know, if I do not create any new user, the default user to the database will be the admin user (which the login account and password are the same as the cPanel login), right?? So, how can it possible to get access denied? I double checked and the database user do has all privileges.